# install Jmeter plugin Web Socket Sampler by Peter .... on Bash / Unix /docker container

Tags: bash, docker, websocket, jmeter, docker-container

I need to command / script, which install me Jmeter Plugin - Web Socket Sampler by Peter... on Bash/ unix

I need this, becouse I configuration Jmeter with Jenkins by docker container. I have a docker image, and now I prepare script, which install web socket sampler and run jmeter test in container.

I prepare following script to install Web Socket Sampler;

sudo install /usr/bin/wget
https://bitbucket.org/…/JMeterWebSocketSamplers-$%7Bjmeter-… && \
mv JMeterWebSocketSamplers-${WEB_SOCKET_SAMPLER_VERSION}.jar ${meter}/lib/ext

but this script didn't run

> usage: install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
>   [-o owner] file1 file2 install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g
>   group] [-m mode] [-o owner] file1 ... fileN directory install -d [-v]
>   [-g group] [-m mode] [-o owner] directory ... zsh: no such file or
>   directory:
>   https://bitbucket.org/…/JMeterWebSocketSamplers-$%7Bjmeter-…

what is a problem with my script?
what improve this script?

Answer (score 0):

Download link is wrong, use the following

```
  https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/downloads/JMeterWebSocketSamplers-1.2.1.jar
```

In your script should be

```
 https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/downloads/JMeterWebSocketSamplers
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to really "improve" your script consider using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager). Some plugins rely on dependencies and with the JMeter Plugins Manager it will be much easier to install the plugins and keep them up to date.

Example shell commands in order to get WebSocket Samplers installed would be:

1. Install [JMeter Plugins Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/)

   ```
   wget http://central.maven.org/maven2/kg/apc/cmdrunner/2.2/cmdrunner-2.2.jar -P /path/to/apache-jmeter-5.0/lib/
   ```
2. Install [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

   ```
   wget http://central.maven.org/maven2/kg/apc/jmeter-plugins-manager/1.3/jmeter-plugins-manager-1.3.jar -P /path/to/apache-jmeter-5.0/lib/ext/
   ```
3. Generate `PluginsManagerCMD.sh` shell script:

   ```
   java -cp /path/to/apache-jmeter-5.0/lib/ext/jmeter-plugins-manager-1.3.jar org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMDInstaller
   ```
4. Now you can [setup any plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManagerAutomated/) using `PluginsManagerCMD.sh` script like:

   ```
   /path/to/apache-jmeter-5.0/bin/./PluginsManagerCMD.sh install websocket-samplers
   ```

Comment: ok, but I need run install this in docker container and use macosx system. what will be command in docker container to install this